# Running Jenkins on docker container.Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am running jenkins inside docker container(jenkins/jenkins:lts) as a base image.

I have created a pipeline in jenkins where i have added the following

```
node{
    stage('SCM checkout')
    {
        git url: 'https://github.com/THIYAGU22/javaapp'
    }
    stage('Mvn Package')
    {
        def mvnHome = tool name: 'maven-3', type: 'maven'
        def mvnCMD = "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn"
        sh script: "${mvnCMD} clean package"
    }
    stage('Build Docker Image')
    {
        tool name: 'docker', type: 'dockerTool'
        def dockerHome = tool 'docker'
        env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
        sh 'docker build -t imthiyagu/java-app-2.0.0 .'
    }
}
```

After the build it can able to process SCM checkout and Mvn package but not building docker image
[image]

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Hope this [blog post](https://blog.container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker#:~:text=Open%20the%20Jenkins%20home%20page,sudo%20docker%20run%20hello%2Dworld%22) help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker` command needs a Docker socket to talk to. The default socket it looks for is `/var/run/docker.sock`. You have two options of providing a Docker socket:

1. Run the Jenkins image with the `--privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` arguments. This mounts the host's Docker socket into the Jenkins image, which can then be used by Docker. Note that using `--privileged` is [a security risk](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/19/l/why-running-a-privileged-container-in-docker-is-a-bad-idea.html).
2. Expose your host's Docker socket over HTTPS: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/. Then set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable pointing to `tcp://YOURHOST:PORT`, where port is 2375 or 2376.

Comment: Isn't docker-in-docker an option?